# Ignore output produced

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an iOS app that monitors input every second. This app also produces music at the same time. The input and the output are interfering. Is there a way to prevent the output from being picked up by the input unit?

Comment: Are you using the microphone for input while using the speakers for output - and the microphone is picking up the music?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AVAudioSession:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: &error];
```

For `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` the docs say:

> This category is appropriate for simultaneous recording and playback, and also for apps that record and play back but not simultaneously.